# Collective, emergent motion, solitons etc. in multiparticle system described by second quantization?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, second-quantization

Multiparticle systems are described by vectors of creation and annihilation operators $a_i^\dagger$, $a_i$ for each particle $I_i$. The atate is described by $b_1 b_2\dots b_n$ applied to the ground state, where $b_i$ is $a_i^\dagger$ or $a_i$. So, such description can fully capture pairwise, n-wise and multirange interaction, but such description neglects, abstracts away spatial structure. But collective, swarming, solition motion is somehow connected with spatial structure? Or maybe not - maybe collective motion is connected with interaction patterns and for long range interaction there can be no spatial aspect of collective motion. All in all, my question is - can collective, swarming, solition motion emerge or be described in the second quantization? Are there some good articles, model systems?

Comment: Quantum field theory is all about the spatial structure. The association between observables and regions of space(time) is pretty much the defining feature of QFT. Are you familiar with non-relativistic QFT? If so, can you add something to the question to explain why you're not sure if the collective effects that you're interested in can be described using that framework? (This is a request for clarification, not a criticism.)